# How to pass all users to form_for dropdown?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have a `User` model. I want display a dropdown in `form_for` for selecting a user from `User` model.  I have a method `full_name` in `user` that can be used to display full name of user. How would I pass a user collection to this dropdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= f.collection_select :full_name, User.all.order(:full_name),:id,:full_name, 
                                                           include_blank: true %>
```

Reference Link : [RubyOnRails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M001593)

Another way,just consider one example for fixed drop down values ::

Now want to change the :temperature control to a dropdown list, accepting hot, medium and cold as values. Then you can do that this way:

```
<% form_for @article do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.collection_select :temperature, Article::TEMPERATURES, :to_s, :to_s, 
       :include_blank => true
  %>
  <%= f.submit "Create" %> <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You will now have to define the Article::TEMPERATURES constant in your Article model. It shouldn't be very difficult:

```
class Article < Activerecord::Base

  TEMPERATURES = ['hot', 'medium', 'cold']

end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
<%= f.select :attribute_name, User.all.collect {|p| [ p.full_name, p.id ] } %>
```

Replace `attribute_name` with the field name where you would like to store the selected value.
The above drop down will have display text as the `full_name` of `user` and upon selection of a user, `id` of that user would be stored in `attribute_name`.

**NOTE:** Since, you didn't specify which value you would like to be stored in the database, I used `id` of the user. If you want to store `full_name` of selected user then use `p.full_name` instead of `p.id`